# How to execute docker compose from outside the directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm probably doing something very wrong, but I'll ask here just in case since I can't find it. Basically, I have no problem running my docker image when I'm on my pc and I just do "Docker-compose run..." from within the ruby app directory. However, when I push the image to the docker-hub, I want to pull that image on my ubuntu server to then build that image. The problem is that when I do so, I don't really have access to the ruby app, the gemfile or anything so it doens't work at all...

This was my error :

`Step 10/23 : COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile                                                                                                                                         COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder296802662/Gemfile: no such file or directory`

My Dockerfile :

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn netcat libpq-dev nano tzdata apt-transport-https

RUN apt-get clean autoclean
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/cacbe /var/lib/log

RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /myapp/

RUN bundle install

COPY . .

RUN rm -Rf node_modules/
RUN rm yarn.lock
RUN spring stop

RUN rails webpacker:install
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn upgrade
RUN yarn install --check-files

EXPOSE 3000

# Running the startup script before starting the server
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./config/docker/startup.sh"]
# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

My docker-compose :

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    # volumes:
      # - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links: 
      - db
    environment: 
      DB_USER: root
      DB_NAME: test
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      RAILS_ENV: development
```

How am I supposed to make it so that on my ubuntu server I can simply pull the image from my repo, build and run it?

Thank you very much.

P.S. I also always get "Your Yarn packages are out of date!"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've pushed your application images to Docker Hub, you need to, all in the `web` service:

- Add the `image:` name of your Docker Hub image
- Remove the `build:` section
- Delete the `volumes:` that overwrite the image's code
- Delete the `command:` overriding the image's `CMD` (consider adding the `rm -f server.pid` command to your `startup.sh` entrypoint script)
- Delete the archaic `links:` setting

This leaves you with:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db: *as_in_the_question
  web:
    image: 'myname/web:20200622'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment: 
      DB_USER: root
      DB_NAME: test
      DB_PASSWORD: root
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      RAILS_ENV: development
```

On the remote system you need to copy only the `docker-compose.yml` file, and you should be able to run `docker-compose up` to start it; it will pull the Docker Hub image and run it.

On the local system, if you have both a `build:` and an `image:` setting, `docker-compose build` will tag the image with the name you specify, and `docker-compose push` will push the built image.

Comment: This is very good information! I will try this as soon as I can. The problem is that now whenever I build my image, I get the "your yarn packages are out of date!" error...

Comment: In your Dockerfile you `RUN rm yarn.lock`.  That seems related to the error; you should make sure the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` are in sync (same as `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` in Ruby Bundler land).

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently trying this dockerfile to see it it'll work... https://pastebin.com/KwjdA7xe

Comment: this worked, but on the server I can't see my rails app. The only port that's open is 80, but even then when I run `docker-compose run web -p 80:80 rails new . --force --no-deps --database=mysql` it still doesn't seem to be launching on the port 80 instead of 3000. In my docker-compose.yml on the server, I had changed the "ports" for the web service to be "80:80" too. Still, when the server runs i see that rails server is listenin on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000... Not sure what's going on

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're doing.  `rails new` is something you'd use to bootstrap a new Rails application; you probably wouldn't run it in Docker at all, and especially not against an image where you've already packaged a different application.  Just `docker-compose up` will start what's described in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Hello, yeah that was my bad. I got confused too! Everything's working now! Thing is, it's running on the port 80 but I'd need my golang api to run on the port 80 too, so I think I mihgt need to use nginx/apache or something of the sort now lol